# Mongoose Schema populate array field from another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two collections questions and answers which look like this.

**question:**

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56a450880c9a072eb092774f"), 
"text" : "Who are you?"
}
```

**answer:**

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56a452930c9a072eb092775f"), 
"text" : "I'm me!", 
"correct" : true, 
"question_id" : ObjectId("56a450880c9a072eb092774f")
}
```

and then I have two Schemas :

**AnswerSchema:**

```
var answerSchema = new Schema({
answer: String,
correct: Boolean,
question_id : {type: db.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question'}
});
```

**QuestionSchema**

```
var  questionSchema = new Schema({
text: String,
answers : [answerSchema]
});
```

So basically, I want to query the data base to spit a json like this where the **answers** get populated:

```
{
_id: "56a451150c9a072eb0927751",
text: "Who are you?",
answers: [
  { "answer" : "I'm me!", "correct": true },
  { "answer" : "I'm you!", "correct": false },
  { "answer" : "You are you", "correct": false }
]}
```

I can query the questions but the answers are not populated by doing this:

```
    Question.find({})
    .populate("answers")
    .exec(function (err, questions) {
        //if(err) res.status(500).send(err);
        //else res.json(questions);
        res.json(questions);
});
```

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `answerSchema` is the sub-document of `QuestionSchema`

```
var questionSchema = new Schema({
   text: String,
   answers : [answerSchema]
});
```

To meet your requirement, it is easy to do with

```
Question.find({})
    .exec(function (err, questions) {
        // all answers are in the every question as sub-document.
});
```

As for `populate`, when you want to

```
Question.find({})
  .populate("answers")
  .exec(function (err, questions) {
     //....
});
```

The `questionSchema` and `answerSchema` should be

```
var answerSchema = new Schema({
  answer: String,
  correct: Boolean
});
var Answer = mongoose.model("Answer", answerSchema);

var questionSchema = new Schema({
  text: String,
  answers : [{type: db.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Answer'}]
});
```